# Problems with Ubuntu update manager

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Could not initialize the package information
An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.
Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message:
'E:The package google-chrome-stable:i386 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.'

I have been getting this message on and off whenever I try to get the updates using the update manager and also the ubuntu software center crash every now and then!
anyone have been having this issue?

Comment: got to terminal and type sudo apt-get update

Comment: Stack Overflow is intended for *programming* questions. You would probably get better traction with a question like this on the sister sites https://superuser.com or https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

i think your server is problem

try this for change server.
 search "Synaptic Package Manager" on "dash home"
 and select following
 setting -> repositoryes -> ubuntu software

select new server on "download from"

or see this link >> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu